# How to scroll to the left or up, when content is overflowing/larger than viewport?

Tags: html, css

Consider the following code. The idea behind it is to make large images more accessible on devices with smaller viewports. The way it works is someone clicks an image and an enlarged modal appears on the screen and the user can navigate by scrolling up/down and left/right to view the parts of the enlarged image, so they can avoid pinching, which would result in an unwanted zoomed-in view for all the remaining content.

```html
<style>
  div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }

  .largeImg {
    scale: 3;
  }
</style>
<div>
  <img class="largeImg" src="https://cdn2.thecatapi.com/images/9k4.jpg" />
</div>
```

As you can see in the snippet, some parts of image (left and top) are hidden and not accessible. You can scroll all the way to the right and down, so you can see both the right and bottom edges of the image, but you cannot do the same in the left and top directions.
Is there a way to make it possible to scroll in all four directions and make all parts of the enlarged image accessible?